# How to put MDI child in the front of panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I use image on MDI form using picturebox.

I put picturebox on the panel. Now, when I open mdichild it opens behind the panel.

Is there any solution to bring MDI child to the front of panel uisng C#?

Answer (score 0):

The control class has method like [BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) and [SendToBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback.aspx).

After showing the child form you should call on the object method BringToFron(), and this will do the job for you.